# How can i open my rtmp stream on react-native

Tags: android, react-native, rtmp

I want to show my rtmp stream in my react-native application but i can't do that. I tried 3-4 module and everyone gave me error. i can't even start my application.

i tried this firstly and i belive this module what i need but i can't use.
https://medium.com/@edisondevadoss/react-native-live-stream-rtmp-video-player-3db9d43c6137

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 875 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-ksyvideo
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.0) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
20 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 18 up-to-date
C:\Users\AGAOGLU\reactnative\agd\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34 Error:
        Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34
        is also present at [:react-native-ksyvideo] AndroidManifest.xml:19:9-35 value=(true).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34
        is also present at [:react-native-ksyvideo] AndroidManifest.xml:19:9-35 value=(true).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Users\AGAOGLU\reactnative\agd\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34 Error:
        Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34
        is also present at [:react-native-ksyvideo] AndroidManifest.xml:19:9-35 value=(true).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34
        is also present at [:react-native-ksyvideo] AndroidManifest.xml:19:9-35 value=(true).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\AGAOGLU\reactnative\agd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\AGAOGLU\reactnative\agd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at then.result (C:\Users\AGAOGLU\reactnative\agd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

i don't know what i should understand this error.